# Get Receipt number on Stripe C#

Tags: stripe-payments

Please how can I get the receipt number on Stripe with c#

My image :

https://www.casimages.com/i/191231053006538388.png.html

Maybe with a Session ID ?

Comment: You'd access the [Charge object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-receipt_number) and it's a [field](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/006703f7e85b48a683b5b996f3d2bb92642b4b86/src/Stripe.net/Entities/Charges/Charge.cs#L362-L366) on that resource.

Comment: I dont have charge object. I follow these steps :
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/one-time

Comment: You do have a Charge object. It's under `session.payment_intent.charges.data[0]`. It requires a little digging to get it but it's all there. I'd suggest that when you receive the event, retrieve the Session(https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve) and [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) `"payment_intent"`. Then `session.PaymentIntent.Charges.Data[0].ReceiptNumber` is the value you're looking for.

Comment: It is not an array :( its like StripeList<Charge> type

Comment: why is that a problem? Like I said : `Charges.Data[0]` works fine, `Charges.Data` is a List<Charge> and you can use `[0]` to get the first charge from it, which is guaranteed to be the successful charge from the session's payment, try it out.

Comment: My PaymentIntent is null :(

Comment: Did you actually complete the payment in the Checkout Session in your web browser? It's naturally null until you actually make the payment and complete the session. Then you receive the webhook event (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment#webhooks) and that's the point where you'd do all this to inspect the charge.

Comment: It is too strange because I have my PaymentIntentId but the object PaymentIntent is null.

Comment: yeah, that's because you didn't [Expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) the field as I mentioned. If you only have the ID you can [retrieve](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/retrieve) it but it's usually easier to just expand the field when retrieving the Session object.

Comment: Sorry my friend but my session.PaymentIntent is null

Comment: yep. That's because you didn't expand it. So it's only an ID. Please read the links I posted describing the `expand` functionality of Stripe's API. A lot of fields are IDs by default, so PaymentIntentID is set but PaymentIntent is not. If you instead had created the Session object by passing AddExpand, then the PaymentIntent object is set. Or if you don't want to do that, you can make a separate call to retrieve the full PaymentIntent object using the ID.

Comment: Here is what I have :

Comment: "<Stripe.Charge@34746906 id=ch_1FvoSUCVaxuh7rlbpi7oZR1U> JSON: {\r\n  \"id\": \"ch_1FvoSUCVaxuh7rlbpi7oZR1U\",\r\n  \"object\": \"charge\",\r\n  \"amount\": etc etc

Comment: My ReceiptNumber is null :(

Comment: yeah, sometimes they are null if you look directly at the event because the number is not generated immediately unfortunately. Try the approach in my answer, but otherwise you might have to wait a second, unfortunately the number is added to the charge asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

You'd access the [Charge object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-receipt_number) and it's a [field](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/006703f7e85b48a683b5b996f3d2bb92642b4b86/src/Stripe.net/Entities/Charges/Charge.cs#L362-L366) on that resource.

You say you're using Checkout. So the Charge is under `session.payment_intent.charges.data[0]`. It requires a little digging to get it but it's all there. I'd suggest that when you receive the event as part of [fulfilling the order](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment#webhooks) etc, retrieve the Session(stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve) and expand "payment_intent". Then `session.PaymentIntent.Charges.Data[0].ReceiptNumber` is the value you're looking for.

```
static void CheckoutSessionReceiptEmail()
{
    var service = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionService();
    var session = service.Get(
        "cs_test_nHUZtpUvaI80YAKGgCMGyeHfjQ6nMtUhVLeVpowWsgpfyGujccGxnAuJ",
        new Stripe.Checkout.SessionGetOptions
        {
            Expand = new List<string> { "payment_intent" }
        }
    );
    Console.WriteLine(session.PaymentIntent.Charges.Data[0].ReceiptNumber);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but my Receipt Number is null. I get it after checkout payment, and the payment is successful. Too Strange !

Comment: I get this message from another forum :
It's not possible to do this via our API. The `receipt_number` is generated and populated only if an email receipt has been sent to the customer. Without the email receipt, you would simply generate your own receipt number in your system. Your can add this as metadata on the charge to find it easily in the dashboard for example.

Comment: For anyone experiencing this. The Receipt Number is always NULL until receipt is actually sent. And in test mode, a receipt is never sent automatically and so this number is always NULL unless the receipt is sent manually via dashboard.

Comment: To add on to @pnavk's comment. In **test mode**, it you open the link to the receipt which you get from `Charge.list`, receipt number is then populated for that charge.